# Color only \nameref

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, etoolbox

I am using `hyperref` in conjunction with `nameref` and `cleveref`, and the objective is for `\nameref{label}` to be type-set in the link color (which it seems by default is red), but for `\cref{label}` to be typeset normally.

I tried the following, but unfortunately, it doesn't work.  Can this be modified to work?  If not, how to best achieve this behavior?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\pretocmd{\nameref}{\begingroup\hypersetup{colorlinks}}{}{}
\apptocmd{\nameref}{\endgroup}{}{}

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}\label{sct1}
Content of section 1.


\section{Section 2}\label{sct2}
Content of section 2.  Reference to \nameref{sct1}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: You're not loading [`cleveref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) in your example code...

Comment: @Werner I know.  That's because the default is to not display the links, and so I already have the desired behavior for `cleveref`.  The objective then is to modify the default behavior so as to obtain the correct behavior for `nameref` as well.  The point of mentioning `cleveref` is that putting `\hyersetup{colorlinks}` in the preamble is not a viable solution.

Comment: `\hypersetup` is from `hyperref`, not `cleveref`

Comment: @RunarTrollet Yes it is.  Sorry . . . I do not understand what you're getting at.  I mean to say that if I put `\hypersetup{colorlinks}` in the preamble it would affect `\cref`s in my document (and I don't want it to).  The idea was then to have `\nameref` turn on `colorlinks` when it was used, and then immediately turn it off again (using the `\endgroup`).  As `cleveref` is not used directly for this method of solution, I didn't include it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nameref` does lots of redefinitions of its commands when`\begin{document}` is issued, in case this or that package is loaded. Therefore, we have to change its definition after all that.

**Output**

[image]

**Code**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\nameref}{%
\color{red}%
        \@ifstar\T@nameref\T@nameref
        }%
\makeatother
\section{Section 1}\label{sct1}
Content of section 1.


\section{Section 2}\label{sct2}
Content of section 2.  Reference to \nameref{sct1}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: This leaks color... (the period is red for example).